# SqlBulkCopy Not Respecting NotifyAfter

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

**UPDATE**:  So this was a dumb mistake and somewhat embarassing.  I had the following line below where I was setting the value correctly:

```
copier.NotifyAfter = data.Rows.Count;
```

So I was overwriting my own value and it wasn't working.

I'm going to leave this post here as a reminder to others that sometimes, you just need to look a few lines lower to see that you're overwriting what you were trying to do.  Hopefully someone will look at this and think, "Ah ha!  Yeah, got it.  Oops."

If someone with more mod powers than me wants to lock this, or thinks it adds no value and wants to remove it, that works for me.

In the meantime, oops. :)

---

I'm trying to illustrate (for a demo) the batching support in `SqlBulkCopy`.  To do this, I have a method that takes a data table (with 500,000 rows in it), sets both `BatchSize` and `NotifyAfter` to 100,000, and prints at each firing of the `SqlRowsCopied` event.

The problem is, it doesn't work.  No matter what I do I can't get more than one message printed.  I know `BatchSize` works, because if I set it very low I can see the rows coming in, but I can't get the event to fire more than once.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**The method:**

```
public void InsertInBatches(SqlConnection connection, DataTable data)
{
    int currentBatch = 1;

    Console.WriteLine($"{data.Rows.Count.ToString("N0")} rows, {data.Rows.Count / 100000} batches");
    using (var copier = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        copier.NotifyAfter = 100000;
        copier.BatchSize = 100000;
        copier.SqlRowsCopied += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Batch {currentBatch++} complete.");
        copier.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkInsertPerformance";
        MapBulkCopyColumns(copier, data);
        copier.NotifyAfter = data.Rows.Count;
        copier.WriteToServer(data);
    }
}
```

**The Output**

> 500,000 rows, 5 batches
>
> Batch 1 complete.
>
> Press any key to continue.

By the end of it, I can see 500,000 rows in the database.  I just can't get the output to respect the `NotifyAfter` property.

Comment: Why do you have "copier.NotifyAfter = data.Rows.Count" in succession with the first NotifyAfter? Wouldn't the latter overide the former?

Comment: Also the documentation for NotifyAfter involves invoking a 'SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler' object with a function as a parameter. The notify would then call that function

Comment: You're... kidding.  Holy cow I'm an idiot.  I've been looking at this for an hour and didn't notice the second `NotifyAfter`.  That'd explain it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok marked as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

> copier.NotifyAfter = data.Rows.Count;

```
public void InsertInBatches(SqlConnection connection, DataTable data)
{
    int currentBatch = 1;

    Console.WriteLine($"{data.Rows.Count.ToString("N0")} rows, {data.Rows.Count / 100000} batches");
    using (var copier = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        copier.NotifyAfter = 100000;
        copier.BatchSize = 100000;
        copier.SqlRowsCopied += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Batch {currentBatch++} complete.");
        copier.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkInsertPerformance";
        MapBulkCopyColumns(copier, data);
        copier.WriteToServer(data);
    }
}
```